# Loading vendor javascript as modules

Tags: brunch

I'm working on an application built with Brunch. I would like to load some* of the vendor-supplied javascript as modules, so that I can `require` them in my code, rather than relying on global variables. **Is there some way to do this, without copying all the vendor code into my `app` directory?**

I tried creating a `vendorlib` directory, but brunch doesn't seem to look anywhere bu `app` and `vendor`. I also tried making a `vendor/modules` directory, but brunch seems to not wrap anything found under `vendor` (even when I convinced it to combine those files with the files other modules found under `app`.)

*The "some" that I'm working on right now are Chaplin, Backbone and Underscore. If I get those to work, I'll move more over later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `config.modules.wrapper` and make it wrap, for example, all files in `vendor/modules` directory. Or you can make add more directories that are handled by brunch to `config.paths.watched`.

Comment: I was not able to get config.paths.watched to work when I tried. Is that a new feature? I have brunch 1.7.0 installed.

Comment: Okay. Updated to 1.7.5, and now it works, but it includes the name of the new directory in the registered module name. Is that how it's supposed to work, or have I missed something in the configuration?

Comment: Yeah. Only `app` is cleaned-up by default, this is handled by [config.modules.nameCleaner](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#namecleaner) function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've copied my config here so the next person can have a worked example.

Answer (score 2):

For those following along at home, this is what my config.coffee eventually looked like:

```
  paths:
    watched: ['app','vendor','test','vendorlib']
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
        'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/
        'test/javascripts/test.js': /^test[\\/](?!vendor)/
        'test/javascripts/test-vendor.js': /^test[\\/](?=vendor)/
      order:
        # Files in `vendor` directories are compiled before other files
        # even if they aren't specified in order.before.
        before: [
          'vendor/scripts/console-polyfill.js',
        ]
        after: [
          'test/vendor/scripts/test-helper.js'
        ]

    stylesheets:
      joinTo:
        'stylesheets/app.css': /^(app|vendor)/
        'test/stylesheets/test.css': /^test/
      order:
        after: ['vendor/styles/helpers.css']

    templates:
      joinTo: 'javascripts/app.js'

  modules:
    nameCleaner: (path) ->
      path.replace(/^(app|vendorlib)\//, '')
```

This lets me populate a `vendorlib` directory with modules from vendors that support loading as modules. I currently have Chaplin, jQuery, and Backbone in there. I had to rename them not to include the version numbers.